# PHP Simple PCRE regex to only allow 1 dot or none?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to create a regex for alias validation:

And I'm allowing letters, numbers and 1 dot.

I have done the following:

```
/^[a-z0-9\\.]+$/i
```

However it allows more then 1 dot?

Comment: Can the dot appear at any position?

Comment: @Gumbo - Yes, it can appear at any position.

Comment: And what about only the dot alone?

Comment: and the dot can't be on its own - appreciate the questions (should clarify any confusion) - I should have been more precise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/^(?:\.[a-z0-9]+|[a-z0-9]+(?:\.[a-z0-9]*)?)$/i
```

This allows the string to either:

- start with one dot that is followed by at least one alphanumeric character, or
- start with one or more alphanumeric character that may be followed by one dot and zero or more alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
^(?:[a-z0-9]+\.?[a-z0-9]*|[a-z0-9]*\.?[a-z0-9]+)$
```

places the dot in the center, then allows it to be surrounded on either side.

Comment: … as well as the empty string.

Comment: @Gumbo: indeed, an empty string included. Placing the {} inside the class doesn't work, and I don't know any way to limit one occurrence of an item in a class other than breaking it out. @sexyprout: So does the original question.

Comment: FYI the quantifier `?` is a handy short form for `{0,1}`.

Comment: @meagar: Touche, just woke up. ;-) And this should be better now, though @Gumbo beat me by a couple of minutes.

Comment: Although I've used Gumbo's answer, I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a good idea to allow a dot as a first or last character, in that case:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+\.?[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

Comment: The comments indicate that the period can appear in any position.

Comment: In that case just replace the + by * in those  2 positions.